# Clarification on the proof for Theorem 9.9 in Elementary Analysis by Ross

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem 9.9:** Let ($s_n$) and ($t_n$) be sequences such that $\lim(s_n) = + \infty$ and $\lim(t_n) > 0$. Then $\lim(s_nt_n ) = + \infty$.

In the proof given in the book they select $s_n > \frac{M}{m}$ where $0 < m < \lim(t_n)$. I do not see where they are pulling the $\frac{M}{m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim(s_n)=+\infty$ than for some $m$ $s_m> \frac M m$ will be true.

Comment: I apologize. I had made a typo which I just fixed. It should say $s_n > \frac{M}{m}$.

Comment: Don't worry man;)

Comment: Though, I still do not understand why we are allowed to say $s_n > \frac{M}{m}$. Where does the choice of $\frac{M}{m}$ come from?

Comment: Because if $s_n \rightarrow +\infty$ than you have that $\forall M\in \mathbb R \,   \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N \, t.c. s_n>M \, \forall n>n_0$, so you can take $M= \frac M m$.